# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Job' with an argument list of type '(text: String?, jobImage: UIImage?)'

Tags: ios, swift

I get "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Job' with an argument list of type '(text: String?, jobImage: UIImage?)'" as an Error when I try to add the jobImage in following code:

```
let newJob = Job(text: textView.text, jobImage: takenImage)
```

This is the code according to the Job.swift

```
var jobImage: UIImage!

init(text: String, jobImage: UIImage, addedByUser: String, userImage: UIImage) {
    self.text = text
    self.jobImage = jobImage
    self.addedByUser = addedByUser
    self.userImage = userImage
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").childByAutoId()
}
```

Do you have an Idea how I could solve this error?

Comment: You need to provide `addedByUser:` and `userImage` parameters, too. If you don't want to do that, you can provide default values to that parameters, like `addedByUser: String = ""`.

Answer (score 2):

Two way to resolve this,

**Solution 1:**

Keep the parameters as `optional`,

```
var text: String?
var jobImage: UIImage?
var addedByUser: String?
var userImage: UIImage?

init(text: String? = nil, jobImage: UIImage? = nil, addedByUser: String? = nil, userImage: UIImage? = nil) {
    self.text = text
    self.jobImage = jobImage
    self.addedByUser = addedByUser
    self.userImage = userImage
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").childByAutoId()
}

let newJob = Job(text: textView.text, jobImage: takenImage)
```

**Solution 2:**

Pass all the required values in method call as per the method `defination`,

```
let newJob = Job(text: textView.text, jobImage: image, addedByUser: "addedUser", userImage: userImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your signature, you need to use `if let` binding to pass all the arguments as:

```
if let image = takenImage, let text = textView.text  {    
   let newJob = Job(text: text, jobImage: image, addedByUser: addedByUser, userImage: userImage)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `init` needs parameters of types:

```
String, UIImage, String, UIImage
```

you're passing

```
String?, UIImage?
```

If you know that you always pass `text` and `jobImage` but you don't always assign other properties, make them optional

```
var text: String
var jobImage: UIImage
var addedByUser: String?
var userImage: UIImage?
```

then you can create `init` with default values for optional properties, so if you don't pass them as parameter, nevermind, property will be `nil`

```
init(text: String, jobImage: UIImage, addedByUser: String? = nil, userImage: UIImage? = nil)
```

---

Now when you want to use your `init`, you have to unwrap optional `text` property of `textView` and `takenImage`

```
if let text = textView.text, let jobImage = takenImage {
    let newJob = Job(text: text, jobImage: jobImage)
}
```